# Clearing a entry containing both a 'Integer' and 'String'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to clear a Tkinter Entry Box by using a Tkinter Button. The problem is that my entry includes both 'Integers' aswell as a 'String' and my code wont clear the entry.

I have tried changing the attributes of the clearing method. Right now it's .delete(0, END). But i have tried changing it to .delete("0.0", END) and .delete(0.0, END. But this is just me desperatly trying things out.

```
enter code here

from tkinter import *

root = Tk() 

def validatecontent(entry_text1):
    return (entry_text1.isdigit() == bool(entry_text1)) or entry_text1 == 
    (".")

def clear_entry():
    entry_1.delete(0, END)

vcmd = (root.register(validatecontent), '%S')
entry_text1 = StringVar()
entry_1 = Entry(root, width=11, textvariable=entry_text1, 
                      validate='all', validatecommand=vcmd)
entry_1.pack()

button = Button(root, width=10, text="Clear", 
                       command=clear_entry)
button.pack() 

root.mainloop()
```

If the entry contains Integers alone it gets cleared. But if the entry contains '.' nothing happens, no error code at all.

Comment: You can use `entry_text1.set('')`

Comment: for you it looks like integer but for python it is string with digits, not integer.

Comment: your problem is `validatecontent`. `delete()` clears all if you don't use `validatecontent`? What you try to validate ?

Comment: If you have `'.'` then `isdigit()` gives `False`. And `bool(entry_text1)` check if string is not empty. What you try to compare with `(entry_text1.isdigit() == bool(entry_text1))` ? Maybe use `print(entry_text1,entry_text1.isdigit(), bool(entry_text1)` to see what values you have.

Comment: Using `entry_text1.set(' ')` did the job for me, thanks everyone for helping tho!